# How to creat an Object in a View in swiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

iam building a small social media app. i am trying to simulate other user, so i made an class called User with the needed attributes. I created an Main user called appUser, who gets the informations that tipped in and . The problem is how and where do i creat the other user and give them there attributes so i can put them into the friend array of appUser.

```
class User: ObservableObject{

@Published var username: String = ""
@Published var name: String = ""
var password: String = ""
@Published var email: String = ""
@Published var beschreibung: String = ""
@Published var profilBild: UIImage?

@Published var friends = [User]()
@Published var friendAnfrage = [User]()
@Published var friendAnfragebekommen = [User]()

@Published var feed = [SinglePostView]()

func addFriend(friend: User,appUser: User) {
    friend.friendAnfrage.append(appUser)
    friendAnfrage(friend: appUser)
}
func newFriend(newFriend: User) {
    friends.append(newFriend)
}
func friendAnfrage(friend: User) {
    friendAnfragebekommen.append(friend)
}

func makePost(image: UIImage,appUser: User) {
    
    feed.append(SinglePostView(bild: image, ersteller: appUser))
    
    for i in 0..<friends.count {
        friends[i].feed.append(SinglePostView(bild: image, ersteller: appUser))
    }
}
```

}

```
struct Home: View {

@EnvironmentObject var appInfo: AppInformation
@StateObject var appUser = User()

let tim: User = User()
tim.username = "Timm"
tim.addFriend(friend: tim, appUser: appUser)


var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {
        
    if appInfo.finished {
        
        if appInfo.home {
            HomeView().environmentObject(appUser)
        }
        else if appInfo.camera {
            MakePostView()
        }
        else if appInfo.friends {
            FriendsView().environmentObject(appUser)
        }
        else if appInfo.profil {
            ProfileView().environmentObject(appUser)
                         .environmentObject(appInfo)
        }
            if appInfo.showBar {
                NavigationBar()
            }
        }
        
        else {
            ErstellenView().environmentObject(appInfo)
                           .environmentObject(appUser)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should pull the code where you make the test data out of your view, and put it in a `static func` in your `User` called something like 'makeTestUser()`. Have it put some random data in, so no two users are alike, and then in the view you could call it with `User. makeTestUser()` in your view.

Comment: I dont know where to put it in my view when i put it in the Body i get an error thats this is not a view and when i put it in the struct i get a bunch of errors

Comment: So i made a func in User which makes new TestUser and where should i call this func

Comment: You should consider making your model a struct instead of an ObservableObject. By having your model being a class (and with nested classes like you have), you are fighting an uphill battle against the way SwiftUI normally works.